# Restore default power settings on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, power-management

I've noticed that Ubuntu 12.04 restarts instead of hibernating or when the battery power is below the critical level, and then continues restarting until the battery runs out, and power is lost. Is this the normal default setting, or is this atypical? I can't see why it would have been designed this way intentionally - it seems counter-intuitive (aside from the obvious risk of data loss). When I first installed Ubuntu 12.04, it would suspend when the power was critically low, but this is no longer the case - why did this happen?

Comment: I think it used to suspend by default, but this is no longer available as an option - the option was available before, but it disappeared for no clear reason.

Comment: BTW, I'd like to know whether this behavior is typical for Ubuntu 12.04 - was the "suspend when critically low" power option removed intentionally as part of an update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suspend is normal when power is low. Open up "System Preferences" and click "Power". There it will tell you what it does when the power is low or system idle etc.

If you want alternate power management then you can always install Jupiter.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jupiter
```

After you've done that logout and log back in.
If you don't like it then you can remove it with:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge jupiter
```

Comment: The only power option available for my Ubuntu 12.04 installation is "Power off", and "hibernate" is grayed out. Is this the typical default setting?

Comment: By default it is disabled. I just checked the documentation. You can re-enable it by following this guide: http://www.howtogeek.com/113923/how-to-re-enable-hibernate-in-ubuntu-12.04/

Comment: Is "suspend" disabled by default as well? Also, where did you find the documentation?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html

Comment: On my computer (Lenovo Z560), the computer suspends properly when I'm using the Cinnamon desktop environment, but not with the Unity desktop environment.